# Laravel Blade, using pluck on collection does not return an array

Tags: php, laravel

Hope one of you can help me with a problem.

I get an error, telling me i'm not using an array with in_array().

Using pluck() should get me an array, right?

```
{{ Request::ip() }}
{{ $pug->ipbans->pluck('ip') }}

Output:
127.0.0.1
["127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1"]
```

Then in Blade:

```
@if( in_array( Request::ip(), $pug->ipbans->pluck('ip')  ) )
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        Your IP has been blocked on this page. Changes not allowed.
    </div>
@endif
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given (View: ...)
```

So it tells me that `$pug->ipbans->pluck('ip')` is not an array - but it is, right?

Comment: just add toArray()
$pug->ipbans->pluck('ip')->toArray();

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. So a collection is not an array? I thought it was. Post an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

according to [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_pluck)

the collection method 'pluck' return a collection not an array

to make the result an array you can use 'all':

```
{{ $pug->ipbans->pluck('ip')->all() }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$pug->ipbans->pluck('ip')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add toArray()

```
 $pug->ipbans->pluck('ip')->toArray();
```